# how to add custom button in MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a project to play videofile through MPMoviePlayerViewController,
that process i was finished.in MPMoviePlayerViewController, how i add button like conrols.

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerViewController is just like any other view controller. You should be able to set up your own custom view and then hook up your buttons to the moviePlayer contained in the MPMoviePlayerViewController

Answer (score 0):

are you want to creating the customization of the MPMovieViewController for that below code is use to create the customized Moviecontroller..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    MainScreenVCtr *tempVariable=[[MainScreenVCtr alloc] initWithNibName:(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM())?@"MainScreeniPad":@"MainScreenVCtr" bundle:nil];

    self.nvCtr=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tempVariable];

    self.nvCtr.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height-20);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [self.window addSubview:self.nvCtr.view];

    self.vCtr=[[CustomControllsVCtr alloc] initWithNibName:(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM())?@"CustomControllsiPad":@"CustomControllsVCtr" bundle:nil];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

[And refer the reference link and Download the source code and implementation tutorail given here.](http://sugartin.info/2011/09/07/creating-customized-movieplayer-in-iphone-ipad-both/)

Hope this tutorial help to you create customized MPViewcontroller .

Happy Codeing